# Check if a page is already opened

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a reliable way to know if an other instance of the same page is already opened in the browser?
I’ve tried setting up a variable in local storage at load and unload but mobile browsers do not always send the unload event..

Answer (score 0):

The context of JavaScript code is per opened page (called window). Therefore, there is no reliable way to track open pages unless you open a WebSocket connection to the server and check the number of open pages by associating a unique identifier to each of them and prevent opening multiple pages. If you want to take this approach, search for a WebSocket implementation of your server-side application.